# Building a sentence with the word "impatience"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct to say that?

> I do not like waiting for E-mail replies with **impatience**

Or

> I am **impatient**, so I do not like waiting for e-mail

How could I express that thought a more natural way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your first version, you're saying that the thing you dislike is to wait with impatience for email. Presumably, waiting *patiently* for email is fine. In your second version, your impatience is the reason you give for disliking the wait. Add a comma just before *so* and a full stop at the end, and the part after 'or' sounds okay.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence! so, should i say ' I do not like waiting patiently for email replies' Instead of first sentence?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll address your question with its follow-up in an answer.

Comment: Why not just say, "I'm rather impatient when waiting for email."

Answer (score 0):

In your first version, you're saying that the thing you dislike is to wait with impatience for email. Presumably, waiting *patiently* for email is fine.

In the second version, your impatience is the reason you give for disliking the wait. Add a comma just before *so* and a full stop a, and the part after 'or' sounds natural.

Returning to your first version, changing "impatience" to "patience" doesn't help, even if we change it to an adverb as you [suggested](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103419/sentence-with-impatience?noredirect=1#comment204498_103419) (in comments under your question):

- I do not like waiting impatiently for E-mail replies
- I do not like waiting patiently for E-mail replies

The problem is that *not* has a choice of two things to modify. It can modify "waiting" or it can modify the manner of waiting. Arguably, *not* is more readily understood to modify *patiently* (or impatience), especially in your original version, but there is an inherent ambiguity in the sentence. In any case, it doesn't reliably say that you don't like *waiting*.

Separating *(im)patient* from *waiting* as you do in your second version makes it clear what you don't like, and why you don't like it.